# SQL - Sum of wages group by other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like below (This is trimmed version, this table contains 11-12 Billion rows with 25 years worth of data.
Need to sum gw based on pType as category and separated by combination of eid and cid

```
eid cid ID      pDate   pFreq   gw      PHrs    pType
637 163 2037    1/8/21  1       8.13    NULL    S
637 163 2037    1/8/21  1       162.5   NULL    V
228 787 2037    1/8/21  1       8.13    NULL    S
228 787 2037    1/8/21  1       162.5   NULL    V
637 163 2037    1/8/21  1       474.5   NULL    R
228 787 2037    1/8/21  1       474.5   NULL    R
637 163 2037    1/8/21  1       130     NULL    H
228 787 2037    1/8/21  1       130     NULL    H
637 163 2037    1/15/21 1       602.88  NULL    R
228 787 2037    1/15/21 1       602.88  NULL    R
637 163 2037    1/22/21 1       32.5    NULL    V
228 787 2037    1/22/21 1       619.13  NULL    R
637 163 2037    1/22/21 1       619.13  NULL    R
228 787 2037    1/22/21 1       32.5    NULL    V
228 787 2037    1/27/21 1       300     NULL    B
637 163 2037    1/27/21 1       300     NULL    B
637 163 2037    1/29/21 1       48.75   NULL    V
228 787 2037    1/29/21 1       48.75   NULL    V
637 163 2037    1/29/21 1       248.14  NULL    O
637 163 2037    1/29/21 1       425.26  NULL    R
228 787 2037    1/29/21 1       248.14  NULL    O
228 787 2037    1/29/21 1       425.26  NULL    R
637 163 2037    1/29/21 1       130     NULL    H
228 787 2037    1/29/21 1       130     NULL    H
637 163 2037    2/5/21  1       65      NULL    S
228 787 2037    2/5/21  1       65      NULL    S
637 163 2037    2/5/21  1       587.11  NULL    R
228 787 2037    2/5/21  1       587.11  NULL    R
228 787 2037    2/12/21 1       617.99  NULL    R
637 163 2037    2/12/21 1       617.99  NULL    R
637 163 2037    2/19/21 1       635.7   NULL    R
228 787 2037    2/19/21 1       635.7   NULL    R
637 163 2037    2/26/21 1       654.06  NULL    R
228 787 2037    2/26/21 1       654.06  NULL    R
637 163 2037    3/5/21  1       162.5   NULL    V
228 787 2037    3/5/21  1       489.45  NULL    R
637 163 2037    3/5/21  1       489.45  NULL    R
228 787 2037    3/5/21  1       162.5   NULL    V
637 163 2037    3/12/21 1       24.38   NULL    O
637 163 2037    3/12/21 1       650     NULL    R
228 787 2037    3/12/21 1       24.38   NULL    O
228 787 2037    3/12/21 1       650     NULL    R
637 163 2037    3/19/21 1       614.74  NULL    R
228 787 2037    3/19/21 1       614.74  NULL    R
637 163 2037    3/19/21 1       48.75   NULL    S
228 787 2037    3/19/21 1       48.75   NULL    S
228 787 2037    3/26/21 1       100.43  NULL    O
228 787 2037    3/26/21 1       650     NULL    R
637 163 2037    3/26/21 1       100.43  NULL    O
637 163 2037    3/26/21 1       650     NULL    R
```

When I run the below query,

```sql
SELECT
  m.eid,
  m.cid,
  m.id,
  p.pDate,
  p.pFreq,
  p.PHrs,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.pType
    IN ('H','N','R','S','V') THEN p.gw ELSE 0 END) AS gw_r,
  SUM(CASE WHEN
    p.pType IN ('B','I','') THEN p.gw ELSE 0 END) AS gw_b,
  SUM(CASE WHEN
    p.pType IN ('O') THEN p.gw ELSE 0 END) AS gw_ot,
  SUM(CASE WHEN p.pType
    IN ('C','D','E','K','M','P','T','UP','US','UV','W') THEN p.gross_wages ELSE 0 END) AS gw_o

FROM [dbo].[mup] m
JOIN dbo.ppart p on m.id = p.id
JOIN dbo.cli cli on m.cid = cli.cid
JOIN dbo.cldt cd on m.cid = cd.cid
where p.pDate BETWEEN '01/01/2021' AND '06/30/2021'
  and p.id = 2037
GROUP BY
  m.eid,
  m.cid,
  m.location,
  m.id,
  p.pDate,
  p.pFreq,
  p.PHrs
ORDER BY
  p.pDate
```

Output returning as

```
eid cid ID      pDate   pFreq   PHrs    gw_r    gw_b    gw_ot   gw_o
637 163 2037    1/8/21  1       NULL    775.13  0       0       0
228 787 2037    1/8/21  1       NULL    775.13  0       0       0
228 787 2037    1/15/21 1       NULL    602.88  0       0       0
637 163 2037    1/15/21 1       NULL    602.88  0       0       0
228 787 2037    1/22/21 1       NULL    651.63  0       0       0
637 163 2037    1/22/21 1       NULL    651.63  0       0       0
228 787 2037    1/27/21 1       NULL    0       300     0       0
637 163 2037    1/27/21 1       NULL    0       300     0       0
637 163 2037    1/29/21 1       NULL    604.01  0       248.14  0
228 787 2037    1/29/21 1       NULL    604.01  0       248.14  0
637 163 2037    2/5/21  1       NULL    652.11  0       0       0
228 787 2037    2/5/21  1       NULL    652.11  0       0       0
637 163 2037    2/12/21 1       NULL    617.99  0       0       0
228 787 2037    2/12/21 1       NULL    617.99  0       0       0
637 163 2037    2/19/21 1       NULL    635.7   0       0       0
228 787 2037    2/19/21 1       NULL    635.7   0       0       0
228 787 2037    2/26/21 1       NULL    654.06  0       0       0
637 163 2037    2/26/21 1       NULL    654.06  0       0       0
228 787 2037    3/5/21  1       NULL    651.95  0       0       0
637 163 2037    3/5/21  1       NULL    651.95  0       0       0
637 163 2037    3/12/21 1       NULL    650     0       24.38   0
228 787 2037    3/12/21 1       NULL    650     0       24.38   0
637 163 2037    3/19/21 1       NULL    663.49  0       0       0
228 787 2037    3/19/21 1       NULL    663.49  0       0       0
637 163 2037    3/26/21 1       NULL    650     0       100.43  0
228 787 2037    3/26/21 1       NULL    650     0       100.43  0
```

Issue is: `gw_r, gw_b, gw_ot, gw_o` is giving me duplicate results. How do I fix this?

Appreciate all the help/suggestions

Thank you.

Comment: Just a suggestion in order to increase the odds for getting this issue resolved: Make a nicely formatted minimum SQL that reproduces your issue. BR

Comment: "Need to sum gw based on pType as category and separated by combination of eid and cid" - Then you do not need to group by pDate or the other fields you have there or you may get dups.

Comment: If i remove pDate from groupby, it is throwing the following error... Column 'dbo.pDate is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Yum.Vee - Then you need to decide if you want the distinct values of eid, cid with the summed(gw), along with the MAX(pDate) or MIN(pDate). You have to aggregate the non-distinct fields into some meaningful manner for duplicates to not show up in your result set.

Comment: Whitespace doesn't cost, you know

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your GROUP BY clause matches your SELECT clause to have distinct summary rows (excluding aggregation functions such as SUM()). In this case, I commented out m.location in the GROUP BY clause because it is not in the selection. See line 36 in the GROUP BY clause below.

```
SELECT
    m.eid
    ,m.cid
    ,m.id
    ,p.pDate
    ,p.pFreq
    ,p.PHrs
    ,SUM(CASE
        WHEN p.pType IN ('H','N','R','S','V') THEN p.gw
        ELSE 0
        END) AS gw_r
    ,SUM(CASE
        WHEN p.pType IN ('B','I','') THEN p.gw
        ELSE 0
        END) AS gw_b
    ,SUM(CASE
        WHEN p.pType IN ('O') THEN p.gw
        ELSE 0
        END) AS gw_ot
    ,SUM(CASE
        WHEN p.pType IN ('C','D','E','K','M','P','T','UP','US','UV','W') THEN p.gross_wages
        ELSE 0
        END) AS gw_o
FROM [dbo].[mup] m
JOIN dbo.ppart p ON
    m.id=p.id
JOIN dbo.cli cli ON
    m.cid=cli.cid
JOIN dbo.cldt cd ON
    m.cid=cd.cid
WHERE p.pDate BETWEEN '01/01/2021' AND '06/30/2021'
    AND p.id=2037
GROUP BY
    m.eid
    ,m.cid
    --,m.location   --Commented out since location is not in SELECT statement
    ,m.id
    ,p.pDate
    ,p.pFreq
    ,p.PHrs
ORDER BY
    p.pDate
```